# Arrayformula doesn't use relative reference in sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have columns A:Date, B:amount.
I'd like to use a array formulae to compute the percent rank of the B column in 2 ways, first against the entire data set and second against the data up to that point. I can do this with regular formulae but want to use arrayformula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A4:A <> "",PERCENTRANK(B$4:B,B4:B),))
```

Works to get percentrank against the entire set of data as expected.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A4:A <> "",PERCENTRANK(B4:B,B4:B),))
```

This is what I tried to use to get the result up to that date, but just gives same result as above.

I'm sure I'm not grasping something about the nature of arrayformula...
Thanks in advance

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: usage of $ while using ARRAYFORMULA is pointless. job of AF is to process ranges while $ is used as "locking mechanism" for range mainly used when dragging formula not using the AF

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sumif` to get it.

- Column C: `=filter(B2:B/(sum(B:B)),B2:B<>"")`
- Column D: `=filter(B2:B/(Sumif(A:A,"<="&A2:A,B:B)),B2:B<>"")`

[image]